# dynamic source list for CMake

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

I try to configire my CMake project so it can accept dynamic source list. But for some reason I get empty list from file function. So I've tried to execute the same operation in 2 ways:

[1] static list (the unwanted way)

```
set(VARIANT_A "src/dir1/*.cpp src/dur2/*.cpp src/dir3/*.cpp") 
file(GLOB SRC . ${VARIANT_A})  
messages(${SRC})
```

*here I get the file list I need.*

[2] dynamic list (that what I want to do)

```
set(VARIANT_B "dir1 dir2 dir3")
string(REPLACE " " ";" DirList ${VARIANT_B})
set(Sources "")
foreach(Dir ${DirList})
    set(Sources "src/${Source}/*cpp ${Sources}")
endforeach()
message(${Sources})
file(GLOB SRC . ${Sources})
messages(${SRC})
```

here I get the empty list for some reason despite the fact that `message(${Sources})` prints out the same string as `${VARIANT_A}` does.

So what I do wrong?

Comment: Enclosed into **double quotes** a value is **never** a list but just a string (single value). Remove that double quotes. You may examine difference between a list and just a string by `message()` call if you put printed argument into double quotes: `message("{Sources}")`. A list's elements will be printed as separated by semicolon (`;`), otherwise a space will  be printed as a separator of words in a string.

Answer (score 0):

To create a list you do like this

```
set(VARIANT_A "src/dir1/*.cpp;src/dur2/*.cpp;src/dir3/*.cpp") 
list(LENGTH VARIANT_A iCount)
message( "LENGTH=${iCount}" )
```

[CMake Tutorial](http://goorep.se:1001/changelog/report/rSelect/PAGE_result.htm?alias=guest&set=api&query=Book%20pages&$$TArticleBook1.ArticleBookK=7107&link=%5B%5B%229F1E006D78894848838A0970E2FF0BE9zoom%22,%22Object1%22,7107%5D%5D&rows=25)